# How to make a child div the width of the parent div when the child has position:absolute and some padding

Tags: html, css

How can I make a child div the width of the parent div when the child has position:absolute and some padding?

Here's the example. I want the child to not extend past the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/usv9R/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/usv9R/1/

If you manually set top/left/right/bottom, without setting the width explicitly, it will expand to the parent.  I've set this to `12px` for all which gives the padding effect

Note the `position:relative;` on the parent, otherwise the child will be absolute to the parent's parent and so on.

This has one unfortunately consequences.  One, which you may already be aware of, the parent won't expand to fit the child.

Also, it just occurred to me that you maybe wanted the padding on the child instead?  You can do that just fine, but be forewarned that given the above limitation, the parent won't necessarily encompass the child with too much vertical padding.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to the parent, so that the child uses it for relative sizes rather than the page.
Then add `left:0px;right:0px;` to the child, and remove the width so it calculates it itself.

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/usv9R/10/